# Partial Derivative Confusing Notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

(please see the image attached)
[image: Elements of Partial Differential Equations]
I understand that if $F$ is defined as a function of independent variables $x$,$y$, and $z$, as $F(x,y,z)$ = $f(x,y) - z$ , then :
$∂F/∂x$ = $∂f/∂x$ and same for $y$. Then in order for it to equal to '$p$', as it does in the book (Ian N. Sneddon), we should define $∂f/∂x$ as $p$, no? 
Isn't it better to define $F$ as a function of $x$, $y$, and, say, $t$ instead of $z$?

Comment: You're absolutely correct, it _is_ confusing to use $z$ both as dependent and independent variable. Of course, (12) should read $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=p,\quad\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=q,$$ and it would be perfect if the author mentioned that $z=f(x,y)$ is equivalent with $F(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z=0$. But who's perfect?

Comment: Throughout the chapters of PDE, we use $p$ to mean $∂z/∂x$. If I accept it and wish to use this notation, can I just avoid using $z$ as an independent variable and use $t$ instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue and say that there is nothing wrong with the author's presentation. Given $S$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (with $x,y,z$ as the coordinate functions) we must have $x,y$ or $z$ being locally expressible as a smooth function of the other two variables i.e $y = g(x,z), z = f(x,y)$ or $x = h(y,z)$. So what we are saying here is that, in the definition of $S$, for any $p = (x,y,z)|_p \in S$, we have that $x,y$ and $z$ cannot all be independent variables.

Thus, as soon as you say $S$ is a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is already assumed that if you start with coordinate functions $x,y,z$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, then they all can't be independent when restricted to $S$. Some texts go as far as defining $(x,y,z)|_S=(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}, \tilde{z})$, but there is no need for renaming, there's already enough notation going on to start with. Also, the author is defining those partials of $z$ w.r.t $x,y$ to be $p,q$, it follows automatically txt $f_x,f_y$ are $p,q$ respectively.

Comment: "Then they all can't be independent" I am well aware of that. But are you really saying that he took partial derivative w.r.t. a dependent variable $z$? I have asked many questions relating to this and always got the same response : define a function of 3 independent variables $x,y$ and $z$ and then take partial derivatives.

Comment: Remember that he did compute partial of $F$ w.r.t. $z$. What the person before you said is the confirmation I was looking for. Still, I am open to other possibilities as well.

Comment: You have to look at what I'm saying. We are associating $z$ and $z|_{\textbf{Image}(f)}$. So when we writes $F_z$ that is the global identity variable $z$ i.e $z$ is independent in this case. This is the reason why $F = f(x,y) - z$ is not identically zero. So you can do this association, you just need to make sure that you know what's going how and how that association affects things. The author handles it well.